# How can I uninstall the Cyanogen Mod 7 for my Htc Incredible 2?

Tags: cyanogenmod, uninstallation, htc-droid-incredible-2

I bought an HTC Incredible 2 on Amazon and found out that it is modded with Cyanogenmod 7. I didn't install it myself. Is it possible to uninstall CM7, or is it just built in? It doesnt even look like how an HTC Incredible should look or act.

Im wondering if I got another version of the HTC Incredible 2, but I didnt think there is another version.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2094422It's probably a refurbished model that you bought from the Amazon marketplace, and not from Amazon itself (this model is out of production for some time). Generally, CyanogenMod 7 is very stable, often more stable than HTC's original software. And it has features that the original might not have (Wifi-Tethering, less bloat, pure Android 2.3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you purchased a used phone on Amazon. CyanogenMod is an extremely popular Android ROM that tries to give you something close to a "Pure" Android experience by removing customizations that HTC and other manufacturers put on the phone. **Personally, I would recommend you keep CyanogenMod.**

But if you just don't like CM, there is a [tutorial on XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1466295) that will guide you through the process of restoring the phone back to its original state. **Restoring the default software looks pretty difficult** for the Incredible 2.

You will need to get...

1. [The HTC ADB Driver](http://downloads.unrevoked.com/HTCDriver3.0.0.007.exe)
2. [The Android Software Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
3. [The SuperOneClick tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682)
4. Apparently, two versions (Links: [2.2](https://jellybellys.minus.com/lbeNiU4yKssQzm) and [2.3](http://jellybellys.minus.com/le73lgG8CaI0t)) of the Android software for your phone.

The steps to follow are listed in that post, but they **may be outdated**. If they're wrong, or if you mess up somehow, **your phone could very well get broken permanently**.

All in all, you're free to try to remove CM from your phone. However, you may want to consider keeping it for two reasons:

1. CyanogenMod is considered by many to be superior to HTC Sense (Especially older versions like on the Incredible II).
2. Trying to remove it could lead to very bad things, like a permanently broken phone.

*Please note that all the links are provided by third parties, not by HTC. I got the links from the [XDA Post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1466295) that I linked to in the second paragraph*